# How can I get the project size of a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, cloc

for a current project I try to characterize packages (.whl, .jar, ...) by project size. For packages like .whl files this is quite easy, I just run cloc against the unpacked archive.

Doing the same for .jar files is not that easy since there isn't anything to count for cloc. Is there any other way to get a rough idea of the project size of a jar file? Just the size in kb/mb/... seems too rough for me.

Comment: Define "project size"

Comment: Good point :) I want to find a possibility of grouping .jar files by their size in LOC. But since with jar files identifying LOC is not possible I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you define LOC?

Comment: Oh sorry, LOC = Lines of Code

Comment: You can try running a decompiler on it